# How can I sort the SOLR search result by every 60 days time range?

Tags: sorting, search, solr, range

I like the solr search result sorted in following order based on it's age, group by a every 60-days range:

- {0 ~ 59days, randomized inside group}
- {60 ~ 119 days, randomized }
- {120 ~ 179 days, randomized }
- ...

In our document, we have a field called **publishDate**, which has fieldType of "date". I was thinking if I can use sort function do this (just some psudo-code):

`sort=((Today - publishDate) / 60 ) asc, rand_## desc, score desc`

Also, if it doable, is this only supported in current SOLR version? 3.x or 4?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doable as you mentioned above with [Function Queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) and [RandomSort](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html) field and is support for both 3.x and 4.0

You can check for [sub](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#sub), [div](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#div), [ms](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#ms) functions to perform the subtraction, division and millseconds to reach to the date range value and have it sorted.
Use the RandomSort fields as a secondary sort to randomized it.

Comment: Thanks Jayendra, I tried it with functions you hinted sort=div(sub(ms(publishDate),ms(NOW)),product(86400000,60)) desc,random_123 desc

Comment: Yes, it works well. Sorry I found my previous message to you was truncated. Just want to thank you again.

Comment: Correct:sort=floor(div(sub(ms(NOW),ms(publishDate)),product(86400000,60))) asc,random_123 desc